# A shared pointer query from a novice user. I have code below that crashes when using a container of class with member shared pointers

Tags: c++

```
//this is my main Method ,this was an experiment to understand shared pointer usage

       #include <iostream>
       #include "shared_ptrtestA.h"
       int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

        // declare a shared pointer to the class  
        sharedptr_testA* A = new sharedptr_testA(5);


       //class has a vector , push back a new instance into the vector
       A->mvect.push_back(sharedptr_testA::Aptr(new sharedptr_testA::testA( 
       sharedptr_testA::sharedptr_testB::Create(1) , sharedptr_testA::sharedptr_testC::Create(1)
       )));                     

       //class has a vector , push back a new instance into the vector
       A->mvect.push_back(sharedptr_testA::Aptr(new sharedptr_testA::testA(
       sharedptr_testA::sharedptr_testB::Create(2),sharedptr_testA::sharedptr_testC::Create(2)
       )));

       //iterate the vector populated above
       for(std::vector<sharedptr_testA::Aptr>::iterator it = A->mvect.begin() ;
       it!= A->mvect.end() ; it++)
       {
          // get members from the vector iterator

           sharedptr_testA:: sharedptr_testB::Bptr B = (*it)->mb; 
           sharedptr_testA:: sharedptr_testC::Cptr C = (*it)->mc;

          // print contents of members

           for(int i = 0 ; i < B->m_size ; i++)
            {
              std::cout<<B->bytes[i]<<'\t';
            }
           std::cout <<std::endl;
           for(int i = 0 ; i < C->m_size ; i++)
           {
                std::cout<<C->bytes[i]<<'\t';
            }
           std::cout <<std::endl;
          }

       }
```

//this was the main method above and the expected output was 
B
C 
BB
CC

The structure of the classes used are 
 //Header File

```
    #ifndef shared_ptrtest_shared_ptrtestA_h
    #define shared_ptrtest_shared_ptrtestA_h
    #include <memory>
    #include <functional>
    #include <vector>

    class sharedptr_testA
     {
       public:

             // constructor and destructor
             sharedptr_testA(int vsize);
             ~sharedptr_testA();

             // an internal class member defined
             class sharedptr_testB
             { 
                  public:
                  typedef std::shared_ptr<sharedptr_testB> Bptr;

                  //static create method

                  static Bptr Create(int msize)
                  {
                    return Bptr(new sharedptr_testB(msize));
                  }

                   //members 

                   int m_size;
                   char *bytes;

                //private contructor
                  private:
                   sharedptr_testB(int size)
                   {
                      m_size = size;
                     bytes = new char[size];
                     for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
                           bytes[size]= 'B';
                   }
               };

           //class c has same structure as class B above

           class sharedptr_testC
           {
                public:
                typedef std::shared_ptr<sharedptr_testC> Cptr;

                static Cptr Create(int msize)
               {
                  return Cptr(new sharedptr_testC(msize));
                }
              int m_size;
              char *bytes;

             private:
                 sharedptr_testC(int size)
                 {
                   m_size = size;
                   bytes = new char[size];
                   for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
                      bytes[size]= 'C';
                   }

             };

         // struct containing shared pointers to classes defined above

        struct testA
       {
              testA(sharedptr_testB::Bptr B, sharedptr_testC::Cptr C)
             {
               mb  = B;
               mc = C;
              }
           sharedptr_testB::Bptr mb;
           sharedptr_testC::Cptr mc;
        };

         typedef std::shared_ptr<testA> Aptr;
          std::vector<Aptr> mvect;
       };

     #endif
```

//The short cpp file for the above class contains only constructor and destructor

```
      #include "shared_ptrtestA.h"



      sharedptr_testA::sharedptr_testA(int vsize) 
      :mvect(vsize)
       {

        }

     sharedptr_testA::~sharedptr_testA()
     {

      }
```

What is wrong in the above code ? I wrote this to understand shared pointer usage

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? And post real code, the above won't even compile (what's `new sharedptr_testA::sharedptr_testB::Create(1)`?)

Comment: This doesn't even look like valid C++ code, what is the return type of `sharedptr_testB`? I can't read this any more as it is making my head hurt.

Comment: The return type is of type Bptr which is a shared point to the class sharedptr_testB , trust me this was valid code that I was trying my best to run as I ran into this issue on a large project which has the same exact structure .. I will fix formatting ,I really apologize for my bad formatting

Comment: Well, I find this more confusing because of how you are naming those data types. `shared_ptr_testA` contains `shared_ptr_testA::shared_ptr_testB`, `shared_ptr_testA::shared_ptr_testC`and `shared_ptr_testA::testA`. I would urge you to rename these.

Comment: @Angew I edited my code above its creating a shared pointer to a structure in my class using its constructor and the members are shared pointers to other classes defined in my class initialized using a static create method

Comment: @E_net4 I agree , I commented my code and I really hope people can grasp it better with the comments ..I am a novice programmer I apologize with the naming here

Comment: `bytes[size]= 'B'` (and `'C'`) should probably have been `bytes[i]`, right? Isn't that the entire error?

Comment: @Angew thank you so much for pointing that out , I corrected that and its still crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs in your program:

1. The loops in constructors of `sharedptr_testB` and `sharedptr_testC` use `size` instead of `i` for indexing. It should be:

   ```
   sharedptr_testB(int size)
   {
     m_size = size;
     bytes = new char[size];
     for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
       bytes[i]= 'B';
   }
   ```

   (DTTO) for `sharedptr_testC`)
2. You start with a vector of size 5, which means it stores five null pointers. Then you append two elements to it (size 7, five nulls + two valid pointers). The you iterate over it, dereferencing each pointer. This of course crashes, since there are nulls at the beginning. Simply initialise the vector as empty.

   ```
   sharedptr_testA* A = new sharedptr_testA(0);
   ```

With these two fixes, the code [works](http://ideone.com/mDKbgn).

---

Side notes 1 (C++):

- The code is next to impossible to read. I strongly suggest you use a better naming scheme.
- `sharedptr_testB` and `sharedptr_testC` leak memory. I understand it's just a learning excercise, I'd just like to point it out. You'd be better off with `std::vector<char>` in them instead of `char*`.

---

Side notes 2 (Stack Overflow):

If you have a crashing program, you should generally try to debug it yourself before asking an SO question. Stepping through the program through a debugger would easily have uncovered both the issues.

Comment: I will keep these valuable suggestions in my mind ! thank you so much :)

Comment: @ashokv N.B. I just rolled back your edit to the question, to keep the answer consitent. It *was* one of the problems in the original code, after all.